# How to summon a splash water bottle with no gravity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Right now, I'm making a "Fire Hose" item which shoots splash water bottles. I've got the velocity and everything working but for some reason it falls much quicker than I expected, and the trajectory is as if I've thrown it. I've tried the NoGravity tag but it isn't working, so if there is a way to get it to go where the cursor is pointing aside from raycasting and spawning it in at that block that would be great. Here's my function to shoot it: the summon command is on line two:

```
    #summon water
    summon minecraft:potion ^ ^ ^1 {NoGravity:1,CustomName:"\"firewandwater\"",Potion:{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water"}}}
    
    #get player and water data into scoreboards
    execute as @s store result score @s fwx run data get entity @s Pos[0] 100
    execute as @s store result score @s fwy run data get entity @s Pos[1] 100
    execute as @s store result score @s fwz run data get entity @s Pos[2] 100
    
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result score @s fwx run data get entity @s Pos[0] 100
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result score @s fwy run data get entity @s Pos[1] 100
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result score @s fwz run data get entity @s Pos[2] 100
    
    #subtract the two to get a momentum/velocity and put into water's scoreboard
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result score @s fwx run scoreboard players operation @s fwx -= @p fwx
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result score @s fwy run scoreboard players operation @s fwy -= @p fwy
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result score @s fwz run scoreboard players operation @s fwz -= @p fwz
    
    #tp the water so it's like it's going from eye position
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] at @s run tp @s ~ ~1.62 ~
    
    #put the subtracted value into the potion's Motion
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result entity @s Motion[0] double 0.01 run scoreboard players get @s fwx
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result entity @s Motion[1] double 0.01 run scoreboard players get @s fwy
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] store result entity @s Motion[2] double 0.01 run scoreboard players get @s fwz
    
    #reset the scoreboards
    scoreboard players reset @e fwx
    scoreboard players reset @e fwy
    scoreboard players reset @e fwz
    execute run scoreboard players reset firewandClicks
    execute run scoreboard players set @e firewandClicks 0
    
    #reset customName so ater isn't affected by new ater
    execute as @e[name=firewandwater] at @s run data merge entity @s {CustomName:""}
```

The water should be hitting the top of the brick wall, but instead, it hits the middle:

[image]

Also, I'm playing on version 1.13.

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the problem? The summoning part itself doesn't seem to be faulty, as `NoGravity:1` seems to be working when I run only the summoning command. Try to find the part of code that prevents the potion from flying straight, or include a world download so we can take a closer look at your problem.

Comment: Just realized I had lines identical to the Motion[] ones but with direction[] and power[] which led to it going in the wrong trajectory. Problems with reusing old code I guess.

Comment: So you got it working properly now?

Comment: @Quijibo Yeah it works however I made a new question at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349225/java-minecraft-1-13-summoned-projectiles-in-front-of-player-freeze-and-then-te for a different issue I had with it.

Comment: These commands look very familiar. Did you just repost your question?

Comment: @Fabian No it's one of many different problems I had involving the same code. I'm working on a bigger type project so basically all of my questions are using related or reused commands. Is it ok for questions to reuse code if they are different questions or should all of the problems with a piece of code go in the same question?

Comment: It's the opposite, you should indeed ask separate questions for separate problems, but you should also reduce the amount of code you put in to only that part that causes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Just realized I had lines identical to the `Motion[]` ones but with `direction[]` and `power[]` which led to it going in the wrong trajectory. Problems with reusing old code I guess.

Moved from comment by the original asker so this doesn't appear to be unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

Get a repeating, always active command block. Type in `/execute @e[type=splash_potion] ~~~ tp @e[type=splash_potion, r=3] ~~~` (use coordinates with decimals to get it to move, for example: `~.3~~` or `~~~.4`). That should work.

Comment: If you didn't notice from the comments on the question, this problem was already solved. There's a new question about this topic [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349225/java-minecraft-1-13-summoned-projectiles-in-front-of-player-freeze-and-then-te).